# Querying TEXT column containing valid JSON using SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I wish to query a valid json placed in a column of type TEXT(not JSON).

E.g. I wish to something like that:

```
records = db_session.query(Resource).filter(
              Resources.data["lastname"] == "Doe"
          ).all()
```

What should I do if the data column is of type TEXT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [cast](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast) the column to [JSON](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON) (or `JSONB` if you are using PostgreSQL) to enable JSON operations:

```py
records = db_session.query(Resource).filter(
              db.cast(Resources.data, db.JSON)["lastname"] == "Doe"
          ).all()
```

alternatively, use the column's `cast` method:

```py
records = db_session.query(Resource).filter(
              Resources.data.cast(db.JSON)["lastname"] == "Doe"
          ).all()
```